# How to preload data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out a sane way to preload some dynamic data to get rid of that initial XHR to my rails app after the page loads.

I've been trying generating something like:

```
App.Store.pushMany('category', [{"id":1,"name" ... ]);
```

right in my application.html.erb layout, since I have access to my data on the server-side there.

However, "App.Store" doesn't seem to resolve properly in the global scope, and I get a "has no method 'pushMany'" error.

Has anyone figured out a good way to do this? The way I'm trying seems a bit hacky, but I can live with it, if I can get it working... How do I get a handle on the proper DS.Store instance?

This is what I've got in application.html.erb (Rails app):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    App.Store.pushMany('category', <%= ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@categories, each_serializer: Api::V1::CategorySerializer).to_json.html_safe %>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably be better off injecting it as json, then loading it during the application route.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.preloadCategory = <%= ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@categories, each_serializer: Api::V1::CategorySerializer).to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>


App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.pushPayload('category', window.preloadCategory);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and seems like it should work. However, I get this: "Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined". Any idea what that could be about? Not a very useful error message...

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to load associated records (embedded as JSON objects, not IDs) along with the categories. Ember Data didn't like this. I wonder if there is a way to do this, though...